# Performing efficient local average over a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, 2d, average

I have a 2d-array custom Vector class of around 250, 250 in dimensions. The Vector class just stores x and y float components for the vector. My project requires that I perform a smoothing function on the array so that a new array is created by taking the local average of i indices around each vector in the array. My problem is that my current solution does not compute fast enough and was wondering if there was a better way of computing this.

Pseudo code for my current solution can be seen below. I am implementing this in C#, any help would be much appreciated. My actual solution use 1d arrays for the speed up, but I didn't include that here.

```
function smoothVectorArray(Vector[,] myVectorArray, int averagingDistance) {

    newVectorArray = new Vector[250,250];

    for (x = 0; x < 250; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < 250; y++)
        {
            vectorCount = 0;
            vectorXTotal = 0;
            vectorYTotal = 0;

            for (i = -averageDistance; i < averagingDistance+ 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = -averageDistance; j < averagingDistance+ 1; j++)
                {

                    tempX = x + i;
                    tempY = y + j;

                    if (inArrayBounds(tempX, tempY)) {
                        vectorCount++;
                        vectorXTotal += myVectorArray[tempX, tempY].x;
                        vectorYTotal += myVectorArray[tempX, tempY].y;
                    }

                }
            }

            newVectorArray[x, y] = new Vector(vectorXTotal / vectorCount, vectorYTotal / vectorCount);

        }
    }

    return newVectorArray;

}
```

Comment: The only thing I can see is that you are accessing myVectorArray[tempX, tempY] 2 times, you should store it in a local variable for faster access.

Comment: Maybe reduce the inner loops when close to the edge `for(tempX = Math.Max(x-averageDistance, 0); tempX < Math.Min(x + averageDistance, 249); tempX++)`

Comment: Your code contains typos (`averageDistance` vs `averagingDistance`). When posting code use copy/paste, do not retype it.

Comment: `inArrayBounds` is unnecessary, modify the inner loops to prevent trying to go outside the array instead (hint: use `max` and `min` when setting loop start and end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your inner cycles do is calculating sum of rectangular ares:

```
for (i = -averageDistance; i < averagingDistance+ 1; i++)
   for (j = -averageDistance; j < averagingDistance+ 1; j++)
```

You can pre-calculate those efficiently in O(n^2). Let's introduce array S[N][N] (where N = 250 in your case).

To make it simpler I will assume there is only one coordinate. You can easily adapt it to pair (x, y) by building 2 arrays.

S[i, j] - will be sum of sub-rectangle (0, 0)-(i, j)

we can build this array efficiently:

```
S[0, 0] = myVectorArray[0, 0]; //rectangle (0, 0)-(0,0) has only one cell (0, 0)
for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i){
  S[0, i] = S[0, i-1] + myVectorArray[0, i];  //rectangle (0, 0)-(0, i) is calculated based on previous rectangle (0,0)-(0,i-1) and new cell (0, i)
  S[i, 0] = S[i - 1, 0] + myVectorArray[i, 0]; //same for (0, 0)-(i, 0)
}

for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i){
  var currentRowSum = myVectorArray[i, 0];
  for (int j = 1; j < N; ++j){
     currentRowSum += myVectorArray[i, j]; //keep track of sum in current row
     S[i, j] = S[i - 1, j] + currentRowSum; //rectangle (0,0)-(i,j) sum constrcuted as //rectanle (0, 0) - (i-1, j) which is current rectagnle without current row which is already calculated + current row sum
  }
 }
```

Once we have have this partials sums array calculated we can get sub rectangle sum in O(1). Lets say we want to get sum in rectangle (a, b)-(c,d)

To get it we start with big rectangle (0, 0)-(c, d) from which we need to subtract (0, 0)-(a-1, d-1) and (0, 0)-(c-1, b-1) and add add back rectangle (0, 0)-(a-1, b-1) since it was subtracted twice.

This way your can get rid of your inner cycle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table

Comment: That is very elegant. Thank you, this will make it much quicker!

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely want to take advantage of CPU cache for the solution, it sounds like you have that in mind with your 1D array solution.  Try to arrange the algorithm to work on chunks of contiguous memory at a time, rather than hopping around the array. To this point you should either use a Vector struct, rather than a class, or use two arrays of floats, one for the x values and one for the y values.  By using a class, your array is storing pointers to various spots in the heap.  So even if you iterate over the array in order, you are still missing the cache all the time as you hop to the location of the Vector object. Every cache miss is ~200 cpu cycles wasted. This would be the main thing to work out first.

After that, some micro-optimizations you can consider are

- using an inlining hint on the inArrayBounds method: `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`
- using unsafe mode and iterating with pointer arithmetic to avoid arrays bounds checking overhead

These last two ideas may or may not have any significant impact, you should test.

Comment: The point about using structs instead of classes is good, and it will work well with @serhiyb 's answer. I will experiment with the micro-optimizations as well. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, he has great algorithmic tips. Combined with cache locality things will scream!